Generate rig from make human importation
I can't generate rig from a "make human (the software)" body. I have installed all addon (MHX2runtime...) but it's not working. I used to do it in the former version of Blender but I can't now. Someone have an idea? Thank you very much! Bernard.

Are you sure that the addon is compatible with the version of Blender that you have installed? There seems to be a thread about it on Blenderartists.org  here but I've no idea what the outcome was or whether it works with Blender 4.2.

Thanks for your help. Sorry for this late return. I will check the link you're adviced me to look.

A very late answer, but MHX is considered deprecated in favor of MPFB. MHX is no longer maintained.
For import paths from MakeHuman to Blender, see https://static.makehumancommunity.org/mpfb/docs/makehuman/import_paths.html
For a comparison of MHX and MPFB,see https://static.makehumancommunity.org/mpfb/faq/differences_between_mpfb2_and_mhx2.html
